# OpenOCD doesn't recognize the Chip ID

Tags: c, cortex-m4

I have an issue with openOCD, I want to flash an : `ATSAM4S2CA`, and  Iget this error :

```
SAM4 ChipID 0x28ab07e0 not found in table (perhaps you can ID this chip?)
```

I just don't know what I should do to solve it, any idea ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried [asking the OpenOCD developers](http://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/mailman/openocd-devel/thread/52BEA94F.7080608@freenet.de/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the chip is not yest supported by this OpenOCD version. The table the error is referring to is in the source file `src/flash/nor/at91sam4.c`. I've checked in the latest release (OpenOCD 0.9.0) and it is actually not there. You should report it to the OpenOCD developers using the SourceForge tickets system, or you can patch this file yourself if having enough confidence in this sort of things.